# Workflow, Workflows, Workspace, and State Machine-- what is the difference?

Tags: 8, workflows

Drupal 8 core has an experimental module called [Workflows](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/workflows/overview).

There is also a contrib moduled called [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow).

There's also the [Workspace](https://www.drupal.org/project/workspace) module, which is associated with the Deploy module.

Commerce 2 uses [State Machine](https://www.drupal.org/project/state_machine), another module that provides workflow management in Drupal 8.

What are the differences between these four modules?

Is one more future-proof than the others?  Normally, I would assume the module in core has the brightest future, but in this case Commerce picked a different module (perhaps because the core module wasn't ready?).  And in D7, Workflow has a large following.

Comment: To clarify an old question, State Machine was created a few years before the core Workflows module (Dec 2015 vs Apr 2017). As of Nov 2018, the Workflows module still isn't feature equivalent (no events fired, no field type for storing the state ID and allowing multiple workflows per entity, etc).

Comment: @BojanZivanovic That would be an helpful answer.